# Rails: collect through association?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

For example, Topic has many comment, and each comment belongs to a user.

How can I get all the users have commented on the one topic, efficiently?

Now I doing this by

```
@commenters = @topic.comments.collect do |post|
  user = post.user
  user
end
```

And, how can I make `@commenters` uniq? Turn it into an array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could define `through` relation

[Rails through association](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-through-association)

Topic model

```
class Topic < ActiveRecord::Base
  ...
  has_many :comments
  has_many :users,
    :through => :comments # add this line, it will enable association
  ...
end
```

Comment model

```
class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  ..
  belongs_to :topic
  belongs_to :user
  ..
end
```

User model

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  ...
  has_many :comments
  ...
end
```

then you can find users on topic.

```
@topic.users
```

Comment: In terms of how to make them uniq, you want this in rails 4 `has_many :users, -> { uniq }, through: :comments`